# Совместимость GPL-v3 и патентов

Tags: лицензирование, opensource, авторские-права

Хотелось бы понять как соотносятся свободные лицензии и патентное право. Например, запатентовано ПО, использующее third-party gpl-3 библиотеку. ПО в таком случае тоже становится gpl-3. Получается правообладатель заявил, что патент открыт на условиях gpl? Даже если в патенте это явно не указано, как и наличие third-party gpl зависимостей.

Comment: А патент на что?

Comment: @KoVadim на ПО (программу для ЭВМ)

Comment: Если смотреть на исходный код, то не всегда понятно, как именно используется библиотека. Ведь можно через http завернуть и лицензии будет туго.  Но вполне может быть, что на основной код тоже прицепят gpl3, но вряд-ли это значит, что можно будет использовать объект патентования без отчислений

Comment: Но как всегда вот такие вопросы лучше задать юристам. Там может быть сколько заморочек...

Comment: Я понимаю, что можно использовать ipc. Что если линкуется напрямую?

Comment: то лицензия начнет распространятся на код. Но сам патент может включать какое-то устройство, и вот на него лицензия уже может не распростанятся

Comment: А такой код может являться коммерческой тайной?

Comment: не знаю. к юристам Вам